# Windows 8 - Available font families and how to set global font

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have two font related questions on Windows 8 metro style app development:

1. is there a list of available font families, and are they existing in any Windows 8 devices?
2. how to set a font family as a global font?

Comment: Update: I am using XAML + C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not limited to system fonts. You can load your own font via CSS [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@font-face).
If you want to change font of every element use `*` selector in your stylesheet and set `font-family` to your favorite font. I don't recommend using star selector, decide what elements should get your font.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "your-font";
  src: url(/to-your/local-font.ttf);
}

* {
 font-family: your-font;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mohsen, sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using XAML + C#, not CSS.

Comment: Then check this out: http://www.reflectionit.nl/Blog/PermaLinkcec8b888-dfef-47c2-a082-325419560b88.aspx